# changing the type of a element with jaxb/maven

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to generate java classes from a XSD with a XJB. I am running maven plugin maven-jaxb2-plugin in 0.13.1 version.
I want to replace an element type by an other type.

Here is an extract of my xsd file:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="field1" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Test2Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="field2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

If I want to change `field1` from `xs:date` to something else I have NO error.

Here is an extract from my xjb for this modification:

```
<bindings node="./xs:complexType[@name='TestType']/xs:sequence/xs:element">
            <property>
                <baseType>
                    <javaType name="com.test.WTKTest" parseMethod="com.test.WTKTest.parse" printMethod="com.test.WTKTest.print"/>
                </baseType>
            </property>
</bindings>
```

Now if I replace

```
<xs:element name="field1" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

by

```
<xs:element name="field1" type="TestType2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

and I change my `parse` and `print` method accordingly, I obtain this error:

```
compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

I have done some tests and I can change the type of an element iif the initial type is a type from `xs` namespace else it failed!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: up! Is there someone who have an idea?

Comment: Up! Please! I can not believe I am the only one to have this problem!